# jQuery class selector - can I target two items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say for example, you have this HTML code:

```
<ul>
   <li class="hello">Hello</li>
</ul>

<h1 class="hello">Hello<h1>
```

If I accompany it by the following jQuery, then the .hello class text will he changed to "hello", instead of "Hello":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hello").text("hello");
});
```

My question is, what if I wanted to target the .hello class within the li only, would I then be able to reconstruct the above code to something like this?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li .hello").text("hello");
});
```

Furthermore, if that DOES work, what is the limit of items allowed, or is it similar to CSS in that you can sort of nest as many items as you want, such as body header .li:nth-child(1)?

Keep in mind, I am learning jQuery for the first time while asking this question and don't have an editor to test it out at the moment.

Comment: try  $('li[class="hello"]').text("test"); here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h4tgaux0/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `$("li .hello").text("hello");` (noting the space between the element and class) looks for an element with the class of hello that is a descendant of the list item.

To select the list item *with* the class of hello, use:

```
$("li.hello").text("hello");
```

Note no spaces between the `li` element and the class `hello`, just the period.

In jQuery (and CSS) there's more than one way to skin a cat, so for example another way to select the list item and not the heading is:

```
$("ul .hello").text("hello");
```

or

```
$("ul li.hello").text("hello");
```

jQuery's selector system was actually [modeled](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) after CSS selectors.

Comment: So you can say something like ul(space).hello, but cant use li(space).hello, because they are within the same brackets or whatever, whereas the ul and .hello class aren't?

Comment: The space between elements, classes, and IDs denotes that the one on the left is an ancestor of the one on the right.

Answer (score 2):

To target just the `hello` class for `li` don't have a space

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.hello").text("hello");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="hello">Hello</li>
</ul>

<h1 class="hello">Hello<h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track but do not include a space

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.hello").text("hello");
});
```

The space is valid if you wanted to select children elements of `li` with `.hello`. Without a space, you are selecting `li` elements with `.hello`

Answer (score 1):

Another good solution to this problem is to use a different class.

That way you can decouple your javascript from your HTML and make it easier to maintain.

For example:

```
<li class='js-hello'> </li>
```

Now it doesn't matter what element it is. You have more efficient, more re-usable, clearer and more portable front end code.

This should help you with your second question. The answer is yes, you can go deep and something like `$('body header nav ul li.hello')` will work, but is not really advisable as it's very tightly tied to HTML structure, more work for the browser to interpret, harder for the next dev to understand and harder to re-use elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response! Makes perfect sense.